# XLST conversion

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd, xml-parsing

I am trying to convert an XML from an RSS feed into another form of XML which IBM Cognos application can understand. I am very new to this and I am just trying the sample provided by IBM. Following is the .xsl file provided:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:transform version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns="http://developer.cognos.com/schemas/xmldata/1/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:message>Start: Fields to Consider in the transformation</xsl:message>
<xsl:element name="dataset">
<xsl:element name="metadata">
<xsl:element name="item">
<xsl:attribute name="name">title</xsl:attribute>
<xsl:attribute name="type">xs:string</xsl:attribute>
<xsl:attribute name="length">256</xsl:attribute> 
</xsl:element> 
<xsl:element name="item">
<xsl:attribute name="name">link</xsl:attribute>
<xsl:attribute name="type">xs:string</xsl:attribute>
<xsl:attribute name="length">256</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:element> 
<xsl:element name="item">
<xsl:attribute name="name">description</xsl:attribute>
<xsl:attribute name="type">xs:string</xsl:attribute>
<xsl:attribute name="length">256</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:element> 
</xsl:element> 

<xsl:apply-templates/>

</xsl:element>
<xsl:message>End: Fields to Consider in the transformation</xsl:message>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="channel">
<xsl:element name="data">
<xsl:apply-templates select="item"/> 
</xsl:element> 
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="item">
<xsl:if test='starts-with(./link, "http://rss.msn.com/en-us/money?feedoutput=rss")'>
<xsl:element name="row">
<xsl:element name="value"><xsl:value-of select="./title"/></xsl:element> 
<xsl:element name="value"><xsl:value-of select="./link"/></xsl:element>
<xsl:element name="value"><xsl:value-of select="./description"/></xsl:element> 
</xsl:element> 
</xsl:if> 
</xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

When I try the above code, my result set is returned without any data like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
- <dataset xmlns="http://developer.cognos.com/schemas/xmldata/1/">
- <metadata>
  <item name="title" type="xs:string" length="256" /> 
  <item name="link" type="xs:string" length="256" /> 
  <item name="description" type="xs:string" length="256" /> 
  </metadata>
  <data /> 
  </dataset>
```

The end result is supposed to look like this but i am getting result set like above without any data. Please someone let me know what I am doing wrong:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dataset xmlns="http://developer.cognos.com/schemas/xmldata/1/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <metadata>
        <item name="Title" type="xs:string" length="256"/>
        <item name="Link" type="xs:string" length="256"/>
        <item name="Description" type="xs:string" length="256"/>

    </metadata>
    <data>
        <row>
            <value>test1</value>
            <value>test2</value>
            <value>test3</value>

        </row>
        <row>
            <value>test4</value>
            <value>test5</value>
            <value>test6</value>

        </row>      

    </data>
</dataset>
```

Comment: My input is the xml of this url: http://rss.msn.com/en-us/money?feedoutput=rss  I am trying to take the XML of this RSS feed page and convert to an XML which Cognos application can understand. Thanks.

Comment: I checked that feed. There is no `<link>` that starts with `"http://rss.msn.com/en-us/money?feedoutput=rss"`- this is why you have no`row`s in your output. You will see a different result if your remove the `xsl:if` instruction, or change it something reasonable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing you want to change:

```
<xsl:if test='starts-with(./link, "http://rss.msn.com/en-us/money?feedoutput=rss")'>
```

to:

```
<xsl:if test='starts-with(./link,"http://www.msn.com/en-us/money/")'>
```

BTW, you could simplify your stylesheet significantly by using *literal result elements* and changing the `xsl:if` instruction to a *predicate*:

```
<xsl:transform version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns="http://developer.cognos.com/schemas/xmldata/1/" >
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <dataset>
        <metadata>
            <item name="title" type="xs:string" length="256"/>
            <item name="link" type="xs:string" length="256"/>
            <item name="description" type="xs:string" length="256"/>
        </metadata>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </dataset>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="channel">
    <data>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="item[starts-with(./link,'http://www.msn.com/en-us/money/')]"/>
    </data>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="item">
     <row>
        <value>
           <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
        </value>
        <value>
           <xsl:value-of select="link"/>
        </value>
        <value>
           <xsl:value-of select="description"/>
        </value>
    </row>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

Comment: After I changed the link, data displays correctly. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

Check the <link> element in the input.  If the url does not does not begin with "http://rss.msn.com/en-us/money?feedoutput=rss" you'll get no content in the  output.